# Continuously rotating by 90 doesn't get me the initial angle

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, euler-angles

I have a game object rotating 90 degrees every tow seconds, making the object to have 4 possible values for its Z rotation. Since the initial Z rotation is 45, the other values would be 135, 225, and 315.
Every time the game object rotates, it looks for its current Z rotation in a Dictionary:

```
static public Dictionary<int, string> rotDirection = new Dictionary<int, string>{
        {45, "NE"},
        {135, "SE"},
        {225, "SW"},
        {315, "NW"},
    };
```

How ever, it's not finding the initial value (45) since what it gets in the rotation is actually 44. Why is this happening?

```
float timer;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer <= 0.0f)
        {
            timer += Constants.cannonRotationTime;

            //transform's initial (z) rotation is 45
            transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 90);
            int angle = (int)transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
            Debug.Log("Angle: " + angle + ", direction: " +
            (Constants.rotDirection.ContainsKey(angle) ?
                Constants.rotDirection[angle] : "*NOT FOUND*"));
        }
```

There is another odd thing. If I set the initial (Z) rotation of the game object to 135 all the values are found, it rotates to 45 instead of 44:

[image]

Now, if I set it as 225 or 315, no new rotation makes sense, this is what I get:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a dedicated function to round to an integer without requiring to have to cast before:

Mathf.RoundToInt(float var)

```
int angle = Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z)
```

Comment: This did the trick. However, I'm still wondering why this issue occurs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me. Maybe there is some funky float to int conversion  going on here?

I.e 44.99999° become 44.

```
int angle = (int)transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
```

Can you `Debug.Log` the angle before you transform it to an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Its rounded problem: you could use [Mathf.Round](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html)

```
int angle = (int)Mathf.Round(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
```